# Polymer loading JavaScript modules

Tags: polymer, es6-module-loader

Is anyone else finding it hard to locate an ***official*** documentation and/or a working example showing how to load modules?

Loading a module is core to web development, it should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load es6 modules in a browser yet. The `export` and `import` keywords are not supported by any browser. Most uses use a transpiler to convert the modules to CommonJS which can be loaded. Or use a bundler to package them together.